# Is there a closed-form expression for this matrix power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, matrix-equations

I encountered a matrix power series:
$$
X = M + PMP^{t} + P^{2}M(P^{t})^{2} + \cdots,
$$
where $M$ is a real symmetric matrix, and $P$ is a real square matrix. Assuming that this series converges, multiplying the above by $P$ and $P^{t}$ from the left and right gives
$$
PXP^{t} = PMP^{t} + P^{2}M(P^{t})^{2} + \cdots.
$$
Hence it follows that
$$
M = X - PXP^{t},
$$
but I couldn't find a way to solve this for $X$.

Of course, when $P$ and $M$ commute, we have
$$
X = (1-PP^{t})^{-1}M.
$$
Yet I don't want to make such an assumption.

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: Can you assume that $P$ is orthogonal or orthonormal? Or that $||P||<c$ for a certain norm and a certain constant?

Comment: @flawr Unfortunately, I can't. Is the equation simplified in any way in such cases?

Comment: Is $P$ regular? Without any constraints you can perhaps only solve it numerically.

Comment: @flawr I guess I can assume that $P$ is invertible, if it simplifies the problem.

Comment: $P^TXP - X + M = 0$ is simply the [discrete Lyapunov Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_equation). You can solve for $X$ using the vectorization operation.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 I see. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thank you very much, you should add this as an answer!